# Deploying Spotify web app: Changing Redirect URI from http://localhost:3000/callback to a web address

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-amplify, spotify

I'm trying to deploy a spotify web app. I registered a domain using AWS amplify, and the app works until it calls the spotify api, upon which I get a INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI error.

How do I registered a redirect URI in AWS Amplify? I can't figure it out.

I changed the 'http://localhost:3000/callback' redirect URI to the main domain name of my website within my code base and also in the Spotify developer dashboard.

Comment: Please give us more information. It is common for "Invalid redirect URI error" to be caused by the URL sent includes as the redirect URL in the authentication request to the authentication server to be != a URI listed in the authentication server's allowlist. However, you said that you had updated your code base + the Spotify developer dashboard. If we assume that you're authenticating against an auth server controlled and managed by Spotify, then it sounds like you've already done the right thing to fix the problem and it's still not working. Please provide an example Auth URL.

Comment: In my code base, this is the redirect url: const redirectUri = 'https://www.soundtracksai.com/callback. In the spotify developer dashboard, I put this into the redirect uri section (see https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/app-settings/). I have the soundtracksai.com domain name registered with amplify. Do I need to set up the redirect uri there too?

Comment: When you navigate to the authentication URL, you should see something like this in your address bar: `https://domain-of-auth.com/auth/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=something&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsite.com%2F&state=blah`

What is the value of redirect_uri or the equivalent URL parameter? This needs to match one of your allowed redirect URIs.

Comment: Ugh the spotify developer dashboard is down....I'll get back to you when its fixed

Comment: Ok, here's the url that shows up https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=c3a859af5f674d61b9aaefe638761f1e&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=https://www.soundtracksai.com/callback. And I'm getting the invalid redirect URI error.

Comment: Then you'll need to add `https://www.soundtracksai.com/callback` to the *Redirect URIs* in the setting of your app Dashboard.

Comment: Just got it fixed! My stupid brain was using  an old client ID that didn't have that redirect URI in its allowlist